# Better way to convert crappy text date string to actual datetime in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm receiving a date in a text file that's in the following format, but need to convert it to a datetime2 field.

```
15-JAN-18 04.19.52.597000000 PM
```

I was hoping to use something easier than this.  Format would be obvious, but I can't use it to go TO datetime, just from datetime.

Technically I could use datetimefromparts, but then I have to deal with case statement on AM/PM, converting to int, stuffing it back to varchar, etc, etc.

Is there a better way?

```
DECLARE @blah VARCHAR(50) = '15-JAN-18 04.19.52.597000000 PM';
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(@blah,1,2) AS dd, SUBSTRING(@blah,4,3) AS mon, SUBSTRING(@blah,8,2) AS yy,
    SUBSTRING(@blah,11,2) AS hh, SUBSTRING(@blah,30,2) AS ampm, SUBSTRING(@blah,14,2) AS mm, SUBSTRING(@blah,17,2) AS ss, SUBSTRING(@blah, 20,9) AS ms, @blah AS raw
    )
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,dd + '-' + mon + '-' + yy + ' ' + hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss + '.' + ms + ' ' + ampm), raw
```

FROM cte

Comment: This looks quite robust. What do you mean, exactly, by is there a better way? More succinct?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps one approach

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='15-JAN-18 04.19.52.597000000 PM'

Select try_convert(datetime2,replace(left(@S,18),'.',':')+right(@S,13))
```

**Returns**

```
2018-01-15 16:19:52.5970000
```

Comment: This is proper sleek :)

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks for the grin :)

Comment: I'll probably wind up marking this as the answer. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to use format in reverse. I've gotten spoiled , weirdly enough with some of the abilities of MySQL!

Comment: @mbourgon There's a number of things I like in MySQL, but on the whole, I'm a SQL Server girl now.   Format() will convert a value into a string.  Has some great functionality, but performance can really suffer on larger sets.